# K6 Get request result in error against specific endpoint URL

Tags: rest, go, get, k6

I am new to K6 and am trying to use the tool to perform a Get request by verifying an API.
When the  script is executed I get a warning that terminates the scrip. As far as my understanding is that this error is somewhat related to Go (if I have understood it correctly).

The result that I want to achieve is to be able to execute the Get request to the endpoint URL, but would appreciate any kind of feedback if I have done any incorrectly or should try an other approach.

**Script:**

```
import http from "k6/http";
import { check } from "k6";

export default function () {
  var url =
    "https://endpoint.example.to.cloud/api/reports/v1/SMOKETESTC6KP6NWX";

  var headerParam = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  const response = http.get(url, headerParam);

  check(response, {
    "Response status reciving a 200 response ": (r) => r.status === 200,
  });

  let body = JSON.parse(response.body);
}
```

**Output:**

```
WARN[0000] Request Failed error="Get \"https://endpoint.example.to.cloud/api/reports/v1/SMOKETESTC6KP6NWX\": x509: certificate relies on legacy Common Name field, use SANs or temporarily enable Common Name matching with GODEBUG=x509ignoreCN=0"
```

**Changing URL endpoint:**
If i change the URL endpoint (mockup url) like below, there will be no errors:

```
...
var url = "https://run.mocky.io/v3/16fa8113-57e0-4e47-99b9-b5c55da93d71";
...
```

Updated solution to run this locally:

In order to run this locally i had to add the certification and key:
**Example:**

```
export let options = {
    ...
  
    tlsAuth: [
      {
        cert: open(`${__ENV.Certificate}`),
        key: open(`${__ENV.Key}`),
      },
    ],
  };
```

In addition populate the execute command with `--insecure-skip-tls-verify`

**Example:**

```
k6 run -e Certificate=/home/cert/example_certification.crt -e Key=/home/cert/certification/example_key.key -e example.js --insecure-skip-tls-verify
```

Comment: Is `endpoint.example.to.cloud` your deployed instance of k6? If so are you able to generate a new certificate?

Comment: Thanks @Christian, this help me to partly solve the problem, in addition I had to use  "--insecure-skip-tls-verify" in the terminal to execute the script locally.

Answer (score 1):

[k6](https://github.com/k6io/k6) is written in [Go](https://golang.org/), and the latest versions of Go have a breaking change in how they handle X.509 certificates: https://golang.org/doc/go1.15#commonname

As it says in the error message, you can temporarily allow the old behavior by setting a `GODEBUG=x509ignoreCN=0` environment variable, but that will likely [stop working in a few months with Go 1.17](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#crypto/x509). Using the [`insecureSkipTLSVerify` k6 option](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/options#insecure-skip-tls-verify) might also work, I haven't checked, but as the name implies, that stops any TLS verification and is insecure.

So the real solution is to re-generate your server-side certificate properly.

Comment: Thanks @na-- the solution of using insecureSkipTLSVerify k6 option also worked.